# What event will make a waiting thread execute a synchronized method already run by another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

In Java programming, if I have a thread A blocked when it tries to execute a `synchronized` method of the same object that another thread B is executing, what event will make it possible for the thread A to execute the synchronized method?

Is the simple fact that the thread B has finished executing the method enough for the thread A to step in from his waiting state and execute the method? Or do I need to call the `notifyAll` or `notify` somewhere in the synchronized method?

Comment: You don't need to call notify, leaving the synchronized method automatically allows `A` to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Tutorial says:

> When one thread is executing a `synchronized` method for an object, all
>   other threads that invoke `synchronized` methods for the same object
>   block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the
>   object.

Java Language Reference says (emphasize's mine):

> 8.4.3.6. `synchronized` Methods
>
> > A `synchronized` method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
> >
> > For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class
> >     object for the method's class is used.
> >
> > For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object
> >     for which the method was invoked) is used.
>
> 17.1. Synchronization
>
> > The Java programming language provides multiple mechanisms for
> >     communicating between threads. The most basic of these methods is
> >     synchronization, which is implemented using monitors. Each object in
> >     Java is associated with a monitor, which a thread can lock or unlock.
> >     Only one thread at a time may hold a lock on a monitor. Any other
> >     threads attempting to lock that monitor are blocked until they can
> >     obtain a lock on that monitor. A thread t may lock a particular
> >     monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock
> >     operation.
> >
> > The `synchronized` statement (§14.19) computes a reference to an object;
> >     it then attempts to perform a lock action on that object's monitor and
> >     does not proceed further until the lock action has successfully
> >     completed. After the lock action has been performed, the body of the
> >     `synchronized` statement is executed. **If execution of the body is ever
> >     completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is
> >     automatically performed on that same monitor**.
>
> 14.19. The synchronized Statement
>
> > A `synchronized` statement **acquires a mutual-exclusion lock (§17.1) on
> >     behalf of the executing thread, executes a block, then releases the
> >     lock**. While the executing thread owns the lock, no other thread may
> >     acquire the lock.